# Increment version number in a file through shell script

Tags: linux, version

I have a file XYZ with below content:

```
image: website/api:0.0.1-LINEAGE
```

I want to increment api version every time through a shell script.
So if a I run a shell script every time, api version in file XYZ is updated like below:

```
image: website/api:0.0.2-LINEAGE
image: website/api:0.0.3-LINEAGE
image: website/api:0.0.4-LINEAGE
.
.
.
image: website/api:1.0.0-LINEAGE
```

Let me know if question is missing info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add this three line of code in your script it will help you.

```
ApiVersion=$(cat XYZ  | awk -F'.' '{print $3}' | awk -F '-' '{print $1}')
ApiVersion=$((ApiVersion+1))
echo "image: website/api:0.0.${ApiVersion}-LINEAGE" > XYZ
```